# Using onclick event to capture the values of cell in a data table -primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to capture the value of cell in a data table each time the user clicks it and update the same in a textbox. I referred this primefaces showcase url: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

CellEdit event doesn't work for me as I do not want the user to edit the cell and hence have disabled the input text box for the cell.
As there is no event for cell select, how can I make it work using javscript/jquery or anything.

```
<h:form id="form">
            <p:dataTable id="cars2" var="car" value="#{dtEditView.cars2}"
                editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellCars">
                <f:facet name="header">
           Cell Editing with Click and RightClick
       </f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{dtEditView.onCellEdit}" />

                <p:column headerText="Id">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">

                                <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />

                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{car.id}" disabled="true"
                                style="width:96%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Year">
                    <p:cellEditor>

                        <f:facet name="output">

                                <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />

                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{car.year}" disabled="true"
                                style="width:96%" label="Year" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:contextMenu for="cars2" widgetVar="cMenu">
                <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="ui-icon-search"
                    onclick="PF('cellCars').showCellEditor();return false;" />
                <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="ui-icon-close"
                    onclick="PF('cMenu').hide()" />
            </p:contextMenu>


        </h:form>
```

This is where I want the cell values to get updated as soon as the user clicks on any cell. This textarea is present in the same form as the data table.

```
            <p:panel style="width:56%;height:56%;">
                <p:inputTextarea id="notesTextArea" value="#{tree.result}"/>
                </p:inputTextarea>
            </p:panel>
```

Please help.

Comment: You asked 4 questions all in a sort of similar direction but all not directly related. Looks like you are investigating different solutions. This makes it sort of time-consuming to help out with each of them and you in the end choosing one solution. And regarding this specific question, split the problem down. First focus on how to get access via javascript to an individual input (plain javascript thing)

Comment: And please, please, please either upgrade to PF 6,2 from your 4.0 version (which I accidentally know from other questions)